# Difference between recursive and system with memory

Tags: discrete-signals

What's the difference between a recursive system and a system with memory?

$$y[n] = y[n - 1] + x[n]$$

Is a recursive and with memory, can a system have no memory and recursive?

Answer (score 5):

you can have memory of past outputs.  thems would be $y[n-1], y[n-2]...$  and you can have memory of past inputs which would be $x[n-1], x[n-2]...$  and you know your current input $x[n]$.

if the output you're trying to compute, $y[n]$ will depend on any of the past outputs, it is recursive.  if not, it is not recursive.

if the output, $y[n]$, depends on **any** past outputs or past inputs, then it is not a *"memoryless"* system.

Answer (score 3):

> can a system have no memory and recursive?

No. "delay" (as in $x[n-1]$ or $y[n-1]$) means memory. It is impossible to have a system that considers $y[n-k]$ or $x[n-k]$ ($k$ being positive) for calculation of the output $y[n]$ without memory.

Even the system $y[n]=x[n-1]$ which is not recursive has memory. The output of a memoryless system at each time $t$, or sample $n$, depends *only* on the input at that time or sample (i.e. $x(t)$ or $x[n]$).

Answer (score 2):

You have two correct answers, but I'd like to add a clear and concise summary:

1. Every recursive system has memory, because you need to remember past output values.
2. Not every system with memory is recursive. E.g., a non-recursive implementation of an FIR filter needs memory. Here the memory is used for storing past *input* samples instead of output samples.